# Events not captured

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-events

I built a chrome extension for the Github Star page using jQuery and Backbone. You can try it here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gpmgjficglcobhpbbkbgklfcpmhpemnb and the source code is here: https://github.com/gregorym/galactic

My problem is the following, on the page I inserted a text field which filters the repositories. But sometimes when I type too fast my events are triggered but are not caught...

Here the code triggering the events:
https://github.com/gregorym/galactic/blob/master/app/views/stars/search.js#L25

And here is the code that is supposed to catch them:
https://github.com/gregorym/galactic/blob/master/app/views/stars/index.js#L14

Any idea what could be causing the problem?

Thanks,
Greg

Answer (score 0):

Your listener is on `self` which is a Backbone view, but you trigger on a jQuery element. Both trigger and listener must be on the same element that extends Backbone.Events.

PS looks like you namespace everything using `name.space = name.space || {}` -- you'd be better off implementing a namespace function, e.g. `ns('name.space.foo')` or `ns('app.views.Home', Backbone.View.extend({...})`

Comment: PS I said "extends Backbone.Events", just to be clear - views, models, collections and router all extend Backbone.Events.